# Hello, I have an error on all of my products it says Liquid error (sections/main-collection-product-grid line 104): internal

Tags: collections, shopify, product, liquid, sections

I have an error on all of my products it says
Liquid error (sections/main-collection-product-grid line 104): internal

i cant see my products help please

I searched on YouTube for my problem and expected to find a solution to this problem and I did not find the codes

Comment: Please post source code of the mentioned section with lines around 104